# Infinitive function as adjective with be and without

Tags: adjectives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

I saw the following examples in a book:

1. We have several new plants **to *be* watered**
2. Maria still has several letters **to write**
3. Do you have any money **to spend** ?

Why in first case did an author use "to be" (watered), whereas in other two he used just "to" (write, spend)? Obviously, letters as well as money can't write or spend themselves, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably just *stylistic*, with ***to be** you would use the *past participle*

> Maria still has several letters **to be** written.
>   Do you have any money **to be** spent.

the meaning of your sentences does not change.